# Getting a type and class tag / binding a parameterized type in the interpreter

Tags: scala, reflection, interpreter, type-erasure, scala-2.10

Given a parameterized type:

```
trait Document[S]
```

I want to bind an instance of this for an embedded interpreter, e.g.

```
def test[S](doc: Document[S]) = tools.nsc.interpreter.NamedParam("document", doc)
```

This wants both a `TypeTag` and a `ClassTag` of `Document[S]`. Note that I need to be able to bind the full type, i.e. `Document[S]` and not just `Document[_]`.

How would I go about this? I imagine I would add something to document, e.g.

```
trait Document[S] {
   def tt: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Document[S]] = ???
   def ct: reflect.runtime.universe.ClassTag[Document[S]] = ???
}
```

(why the heck do I need two different tags to get the named parameter?)

---

**EDIT**: The following makes it compile

```
trait Document[S] {
  implicit def systemType: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[S]
}

def test[S](doc: Document[S]) = {
  import doc.systemType
  tools.nsc.interpreter.NamedParam("document", doc)
}
```

But I still end up with a binding to `Document[_]` in the interpreter, so my type parameter to `Document` is lost?!

Comment: Have you tried `def test[S: TypeTag](doc: Document[S])`? You can then remove the implicit def.

Comment: `test` will be nested in a body of classes, none of which will have knowledge of the manifest type of `S`, so the only reasonable place to store the type tag is in `Document` unfortunately